# c++ Visual Studio error which is solved by changing the class name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I was trying to compile simple class declaration using the guide form this page.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

It was pasted straight from the website and would not allow me to compile. I am using visual studio 2010.

This is the error I received:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'rec'

Changing the name of class solved the problem, but I could not find anywhere that Rectangle is a word reserved for anything VS or C++ related.

How could I work that out next time?

```
class Rectangle
{
    public:
      int width;
      int height;
};

int main( )
{   
   Rectangle rec;
}

class Rector
{
   public:
    int width;
    int height;
};

int main( )
{   
   Rector rec;
}
```

Comment: Post the code that did not compile. Maybe you included something else, or unfortunately the code you copied might have contained some invisible characters in the name.

Comment: The code you put here compiles fine. Show the incorrect code.

Comment: Which project template did you select when you created your project/solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include Windows.h or Wingdi.h, your class name likely conflicts with the [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162898(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

You have several options:

1. Put your `Rectangle` class in a namespace
2. Don't include Windows.h unless absolutely necessary
3. Refer to it using `class Rectangle` everywhere to disambiguate between the function and the class (as a last resort)

Comment: @mega_creamery It may not be obvious that `windows.h` is included in the program. When you create a project in Visual Studio, you can select between multiple different kinds of project templates. Unless you're programming a Windows application (i.e., you're just learning "plain" C++), you'll want to create a plain, empty C++ project.